# Jmeter Distributed Testing: Change the load throughput (requests/second) in runtime

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I've set up a jmeter distributed testing setup with one master and multiple slaves.

In my test plan I'm using a ThreadGroup with 5 threads, a HTTPRequest Sampler and a Constant Throughput timer with target set as - ${__P(**throughput**, 100)} for all active threads in current threadgroup.

I want to change the expected request 'throughput' value in runtime for my setup.

Eg. initially the default value of requests/minute (throughput) = 100. After 1 hour of execution, I want to change the requests/minute to 6000.

Using beanshell script to change throughput only changes the value on jmeter master while there's no effect on jmeter slaves and overall requests throughput.

Thanks for any pointers and guidance.

Comment: See https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server), it will launch an endpoint where it will be listening to the commands so you would be able to change the `throughput` property value "on the fly"

1. Add the next lines to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   beanshell.server.port=9000
   beanshell.server.file=../extras/startup.bsh
   ```
2. Create a Beanshell file like `changeThroughput.bsh` in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation with the following content:

   ```
   setprop("throughput", args[0]);
   ```
3. That's it, now you should be able to set the `throughput` property value during your test execution:

   ```
   java -jar bshclient.jar localhost 9000 throughput 6000
   ```

Check out [How to Change JMeter´s Load During Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime) article for more information.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It worked. The problem earlier was some firewall issues due to which my master was not able to connect to slave beanshell server on port 9000. I reconfigured and after proper configuration, I'm able to update property by executing beanshell script on each slave individually.